# X-Forwarded-Host header should not be overwritten by the HaProxy when it is already set

Tags: openshift, router, haproxy

Could somebody tell how to configure custom ha proxy router(haproxy-config.template) in openshift 3.11 where to avoid X-Forwarded-Host, X-Forwarded-Port and the X-Forwarded-Proto header should not be overwritten by the HaProxy when it is already set. When the header is not set, it should be set according to the HTTP standard.

I tried  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3986281 but it is not working.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 3):

this below code worked for me:

OLD  configuration:

```
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(host)]
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http if !{ ssl_fc }
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

change to NEW:

```
   acl h_xfh_exists req.hdr(X-Forwarded-Host) -m found
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[req.hdr(host)] unless h_xfh_exists
   acl h_xfport_exists req.hdr(X-Forwarded-Port) -m found
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port] unless h_xfport_exists
   acl h_xfproto_exists req.hdr(X-Forwarded-Proto) -m found
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http if !{ ssl_fc } !h_xfproto_exists
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc } !h_xfproto_exists
```